# xelatex and tikz hyperlink nodes don't seem to link

Tags: hyperlink, tikz, xelatex

I followed the recipe at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36109/making-tikz-nodes-hyperlinkable to create nodes that are clickable links to other places in the document. The node links work when built with lualatex, but don't seem to work when built with with xelatex at all -- though they do render to the screen as expected (the green overlay on the node is to demonstrate that `hyperlink node` *is* being invoked, it'll go away when I'm not debugging).

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=green!50!black]{hyperref}

\tikzset{
  hyperlink node/.style={
    alias=sourcenode,
    append after command={
      let \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
          \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
          \n1={\x2-\x1},
          \n2={\y1-\y2} in
      node [draw=green!50!black,rounded corners,opacity=0.5,fill=green,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west,at=(\p1)] {\hyperlink{#1}{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}
    }
  },
  mynode/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white,draw=black},
  edge/.style={>=Stealth},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node [mynode] (a) {Not a link};
  \node [mynode,hyperlink node=LinkHere] (b) [right=30mm] {This is a link};

  \path (a) -> (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

In text, though:

Not a link.

\hyperlink{LinkHere}{This is a link} also

\clearpage

This page deliberately left blank.

\clearpage

\hypertarget{LinkHere}{}
Link lands here.
\end{document}
```

Built with xelatex, clicking the green node doesn't take me to the third page, but clicking the text link (green text below, "This is a link") does. Both hyperlinks work when I build the PDF with lualatex.

Why does this work in lualatex but not xelatex, and what can I do about it? I otherwise like the output I get from xelatex (the layout and font rendering are a little different), but the links are important. What do I do to make the hyperlink node work correctly when building with xelatex?

Using

- XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2013060708 (TeX Live 2013)
- LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013061708  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627)

Simple invocation:

```
$ xelatex mwe.tex; mv mwe.pdf mwe-xelatex.pdf
$ lualatex mwe.tex; mv mwe.pdf mwe-lualatex.pdf
```

I have just determined that using the `navigator.sty` package instead of `hyperref.sty` exhibits the same difference in behavior when using `\jumplink` and `\anchor` instead of `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget`.

Answer (score 2):

Ah ha.

> **TL;DR**: replace `\hyperlink{#1}{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}` with
>   `\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}`

I added below the working (text) link:

```
\hyperlink{LinkHere}{\rule{1in}{1in}}
```

which is pretty much what I had in the hyperlink node. The rule was rendered in green because it was a `\hyperlink`, but clicking it did nothing when the PDF was compiled using xelatex. The problem isn't really with xelatex and TikZ, but with xelatex and `hyperref.sty`. Per https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56802/hyperlinking-a-drawing xelatex only links if it finds *text*.

`\XeTeXLinkBox` was added to `hyperref.sty` specifically to deal with this problem. You do still need to use the `\phantom{}` to hide the rule.

Slightly more than MWE that does do what I want, and demonstrates the difference of using `\XeTeXLinkBox` and not using it.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=green!50!black]{hyperref}

\setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{0pt}
\tikzset{
  hyperlink node/.style={
    alias=sourcenode,
    append after command={
      let \p1 = (sourcenode.north west),
          \p2=(sourcenode.south east),
          \n1={\x2-\x1},
          \n2={\y1-\y2} in
      node [draw=green!50!black,rounded corners,opacity=0.5,fill=green,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=north west,at=(\p1)] {\hyperlink{#1}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\phantom{\rule{\n1}{\n2}}}}}
    }
  },
  mynode/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white,draw=black},
  edge/.style={>=Stealth},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node [mynode] (a) {Not a link};
  \node [mynode,hyperlink node=LinkHere] (b) [right=30mm] {This is a link};

  \path (a) -> (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

In text, though:

Not a link.

\hyperlink{LinkHere}{This is a link} also

---

\hyperlink{LinkHere}{test\ldots \rule{1in}{1in}\ldots big green box doesn't work, text does}

---

\hyperlink{LinkHere}{test\ldots \XeTeXLinkBox{\rule{1in}{1in}}\ldots big green box now \emph{does} work, and so does text}

---

\clearpage

This page deliberately left blank.

\clearpage

\hypertarget{LinkHere}{}
Link lands here.
\end{document}
```